# Facebook authentication within a Page Tab

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-apps, facebook-page, facebook-oauth

According to the specification here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/ I want to autorize user with the server-side flow on page tab. I use PHP-SDK.

My redirect_uri parameter is build like that:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/null/PAGE_ID/app_YOUR_APP_ID
```

and I keep getting:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
```

I was trying many different settings combinations. Now I have filled fields: `App Domains,Site URL,Canvas URL,Secure Canvas URL,Page Tab URL,Secure Page Tab URL` but still without success. Addresses are ending with `/` and are all the same.

Link are build proper by the sdk. I test building it "by hand" without encoding of redirect_uri param and redirect link build like that:

```
https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_USERNAME/app_YOUR_APP_ID
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Page_Title/PAGE_ID?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that question is that facebook documentation is incorrect. Format of `return_uri` that worked is:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/null/PAGE_ID?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID

Answer (score 1):

The format of `return_uri` changed again, the new format is:

https://www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID